# Name/notation for the subgroup generated by all stabilizers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, dynamical-systems

Say we have a group $G$ acting on a set $X$.

I'm interested in the subgroup generated by all isotropy groups $G_x$, and looking for a designation for it.

Thanks in advance!

PS1: I thought about the words 'radical' and 'residual' but apparently they don't work.

PS2: It would be nice if the notation would take into account $G$ and $X$ too.

Comment: Invent whatever name you like and whatever notation you want. Enjoy your freedom!

Answer (score 2):

If the action is transitive, then you are talking of the *normal closure of a stabilizer $G_x$.*

Comment: And in general, it is the subgroup generated by the normal closures of the $G_x$, where $x$ runs through a set of representatives of the orbits.